# android Exit from full screen mode

Tags: android, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

I am working in Android. I need to show my activity in Full screen mode, and i did this using following code.

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Now its looking like this:-
[image]

Now I want to exit from this full mode so my activity should show as before. like this:-

[image]

I have a button which is used to switch between full mode or normal mode, i will switch mode again and again. Please suggest me how can i do this. Means how can get normal screen from full screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is upvote is needed? I think it won't

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As per below code, i can hide the `TitleBar` by your needs,

```
Button full;
static int vari = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    full = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fullview);
    full.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(vari == 0)
            {
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                vari = 1;
            }else 
            {
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);                 
                vari = 0;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Try this code. It helps you lot.

Comment: Working fine tested on 8.0

Comment: `window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)` is enough to exist fullscreen mode

Answer (score 14):

To disable full screen:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();
```

To re-enable full screen:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();
```

I think the key in your case is re-requesting the layout.

Comment: What is ActivitiesCurrentContentView here? There is no class with that name! @bbedward

Comment: This hides only Status bar

Answer (score 0):

From ICS when the Fragment is attached to the Activity, the *FULL Screen mode* is reseted. The best approach is to add the code

`getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.root).setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);`

in the callback onActivityCreated of the fragment(layout id *root* is the root layout of the Activity).