# VideoView orientation change to full screen (show/hide actionbar and notification)

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, orientation, android-videoview

Hi I have this problem on playing orientation change. On portrait, I have the following XML in my layout directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- Player Header -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <!-- Song Title -->
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/videoTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#04b3d2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/song_def_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <!-- Full Screen button -->
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnFullScreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
            android:background="@null" />

        <!-- Playlist button -->
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist"
            android:background="@null"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/player_header_bg" >

    </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which when the orientation change to landscape, I have this XML in layout-land folder that has the same XML filename but with the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The orientation changes without any issue, but I wanted to get ride of my actionbar and notificationbar on landscape mode. and have it come out on portrait mode.

I have tried to manually override the onConfigurationChanged method but it's not working well.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.hide();

            WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
            attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN; 
            getWindow().setAttributes(attrs); 

            // setContentView(R.layout.player_video_fs);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.show();

            WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
            attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN; 
            getWindow().setAttributes(attrs); 

            // setContentView(R.layout.player_video);
        }
    }
```

If I were to do the above, when I changed to landscape it will remove actionbar and notificationbar but when i change back to portrait, the actionbar get slightly weird. See how it get cut off? the actionbar

[image: actiobar]

And changing to landscape, it seem like it's going to blackscreen instead of continuing to play the video.

I have tried a few other method but still unable to resolve. Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, but this sort of "fullscreen" activity with action bar poping in and out is in the activity templates when creating a new project in eclipse, check that out.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue and stumbled upon this question. I know it's dated but to help future developers who come here.

After searching around I found a simple solution provided by [Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685313/1440950) where instead of using a compound or operator (|=) to set the window attribute flags you can simply call the `getWindow().clearFlags(flag) or getWindow().addFlags(flag)` functions

So my revised version of hiding the action bar when in landscape looks like this:

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    getActionBar().hide();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    getActionBar().show();
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: For lollipop version of android and above remember to use  getSupportActionBar.hide() and getSupportActionBar.show()