# How to exit fullscreen (show Action Bar) programmatically on Android 4.0+?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-fullscreen

If I have an Activity with a **fullscreen theme**, set up like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.FullScreen"/>
```

With `MyTheme.FullScreen` defined as:

```
<style name="MyTheme.FullScreen" 
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
</style>
```

... **is it possible to exit fullscreen mode programmatically**? I specifically want to show the Action Bar (with its navigation options) in certain situations, while usually having the activity in fullscreen mode.

I have tried approaches like the following [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9684570/56285). From some comments, others are having problems with this on Android 4.0+ too.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
currentContentView.requestLayout();
```

Also tried `content.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);`, to no avail.

I also looked at ["Smooth full screen transition"](http://nubinewsblog.blogspot.fi/2009/11/smooth-full-screen-transition.html), but it seems a bit hacky for my needs, and I'd much prefer a simpler solution.

Targeting Android 4.0 and above:

```
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Comment: try this 
ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();

not this currentContentView.requestLayout();

Comment: getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); use this sequance also

Comment: What do you mean by ActivitiesCurrentContentView? There is no such class in Android. What I have already tried is exactly storing current activity's content view in a field and calling requestLayout on that.