# Give the user the choice to go full screen in Android webview

Tags: android, fullscreen, optionmenu

I want to build a full screen method into my Android app.

I have everything set up, my code actually is like:

```
case R.id.full:
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            return true;
```

This resides inside my `onOptionsItemSelected()` and works without a hassle.

My problem is: How do I give the user the choice to revert it back to normal? Any ideas?

Also, when doing this my text string inside the options menu is still *"Go Full Screen"*, it didn't change. Maybe a text change like *"Normal Screen"* with the according event would be better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hope that I am not stating the obvious but 
you can try FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN

Comment: Nice one! But this doesn't revert back correctly: The bar of my own app seems like cutted. The top of my app bar slides under the status bar in this case. And I can't revert back to normal...

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684440/android-exit-from-full-screen-mode :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can override onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) method to enable disable or change the text of the menu items. This method is called right before the menu is shown everytime.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29