# Some devices don't follow 'adjustpan'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have a `listview`. Each item (row) of list contains a `textView` for comment and an `editText` for replying the comment. Comments are being loaded at runtime.

`EditText` was remaining hide after keyboard. The solution I searched was to include `adjustpan` in for specific activity tag in `manifest`. After that pan was being adjusted for my **nexus 5 (5.0), nexus S (4.1.2) and HP touchpad (4.0.3). Felt cool.**

But the story was different for **Samsung S duos(4.0.4) and Samsung galaxy grand (4.1.2)**
Even though I tried `adjustpan` and `adjustResize` in my manifest ( Individually and together ) devices hides the `editText` behind keyboard. I noticed a more thing that when I touch the `editText` on these devices. `editText` comes perfectly above the keyboard but as soon as I start typing, the screen jumps up n down and finally `editText` goes behind the keyboard.

I have already tried:

- `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` for `editText`
- `android:focusable="true"` for `ediTtext`
- `adjustpan` and `adjustResize` in manifest
- `stateHidden` and `stateVisible` are not the solutions as I want keyboard on touch request only.
- In some articles, they suggested to put views in `scrollView`, but its not practically possible to put `listview` in `scrollView`.

I've spent two days to find out solution. I think this problem is device specific. Is it so? Did any one faced same problem? How can I solve this problem?

Manifest if as follow:
(DetailViewActivity is the activity where problem is arising)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/appTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value="com.examandroid.activities.SearchActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LearnaptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_learnapt" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/appTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.examandroid.activities.SplashActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SignupActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.LoginActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.examandroid.activities.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LessonActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lesson" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.examandroid.activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProfileEditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_edit"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.examandroid.activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DetailViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_item_detail_view"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ImageFullView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image_full_view" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: show your manifest.....

Comment: Included manifest in question.

Comment: try this.android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this is not solving issue. I am unable to understand why this problem is occurring on some devices, not all.

Comment: have u tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"`?

Comment: and also add `android:isScrollContainer="false"` for your listview.

Comment: yeah @MSGadag , but those devices are responding same as before. :(

Comment: create **layout-v14 and layout-v16** in res and paste you xml layouts there and try.. im not sure buddy. hope it works for you..

Comment: What happens is, by touching editText it comes above keyboard, as soon as I start typing, it goes down. Now if I scroll  the screen so that editText is visible again after that it works well. But here one thing I noticed is that screen is not resized (which is resized in my nexus devices). So if the screen is already scrolled up max and edit text is there at bottom, I can not scroll it such that editText become visible to me while typing.

Comment: i think the problem is, u r adding edittext dynamically..

Comment: :( . But It works fine on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext) u have to desable fullscreen.

try this. onclick edittext.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();
```

reference:

[adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

[android Exit from full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684440/android-exit-from-full-screen-mode)

Comment: I also found that pan wont be adjusted if activity is full screen. But my this activity is not full screen activity. Other wise my nexus device also should not adjust pan.

Comment: Anyways I could not find what's ActivitiesCurrentContentView in code  ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();