# How to make an activity not full screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I use this code to make an activity full screen

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
```

How to I make the activity not full screen again, by a press of a button??

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the full-screen setting from an existing activity without recreating it?

Comment: getWindow().clearFlags(int flags);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android Exit from full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684440/android-exit-from-full-screen-mode)

Answer (score 3):

If u change the height and width replace the values u want .8 and .85 in this code

```
    DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width=dm.widthPixels;
    int height=dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.85));
```

Note: the values not exceed 1

Answer (score 0):

use this functions to go/hide Immersive Full-Screen Mode

```
 View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

 private void hideSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

    private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

more here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html