# How to set different themes to fragments in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-theme, android-viewpager2

I have two fragments in my viewpager. The second one uses soft keyboard. So when the keyboard appears, it needs to resize. But it is not possible with the full screen theme of base activity.

I want the second fragment to be transparent and show background of base activity, but not draw under status bar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
public static void fullScreen(@NonNull Activity activity, boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }
```

source : [android Exit from full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684440/android-exit-from-full-screen-mode)